# Merge PDF Files from Fileupload

Tags: pdf, file-upload, merge

I want to merge four separate PDF uploads' contents and keep them in database as binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy to way to merge `pdf` files. If you're using PHP you can use an open source library to do so.
Link: [PDF Merger for PHP](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/)

If you're using `.NET` follow this tutorial: [Simple .NET PDF Merger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger) which uses `iTextSharp` library.